# Adapt-Strap Angular table expand row

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been playing around with the adapt-strap angular table and have a question I was hoping someone could help me with.  Built into the table is a plus icon which allows you to expand the row, its basically an accordion and it allows you to expand.  What I was wanting to do and I cant seem to find a way to do it (and I have spent a bit of time on this) is create my own button which when clicked expands the row in question.  Basically the button should act identically to the built in button.

At the minute I can create the button and get it to expand a specified row (by passing in the row number) but what I cant manage to do is figure out a way to get that row number dynamically.  For example:

```
ng-click="expandCollapseRow(2)"
```

will expand row 3 (due to 0 index).  The code for expandCollapseRow is:

```
$scope.expandCollapseRow = function (row) {
  $scope.$broadcast('adTableLiteAction', {
    tableName: 'carsForSale',
    action: function (actions) {  
      actions.expandCollapseRow(row);
    }
  });
};
```

I just cant get a way for the code to figure out which row it is in and pass it along. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.  I have altered an existing JSFiddle to show the issue and it can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/2bp4dvpm/

Thanks for anyone who takes the time to look at this.

Comment: when changing `ng-click="expandCollapseRow(2)"` to `ng-click="expandCollapseRow(item.id)"` different rows start collapsing but seems that `item.id` is not the column with the right order. I tried with `ng-click="expandCollapseRow($index)"` but still openning only the third row ... So you can access the item with `item` but I'm not sure what you should pass to `expandCollapseRow()` function

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into this issue.  It is appreciated.  It is a frustrating issue, I have no idea why some of those options you suggested are not working.  I've spent a bit more time on it trying different things but havent been able to figure out a resolution to it so guess I will have to try something completely different.